# oracle apex ssl configuration for ords standalone server

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I have configured oracle apex 18.2 with ords as standalone server ,
For ords configuration i used below command

```
java -jar ords.war install advanced
```

I have selected 1 from below Question while Configuring ords

`Enter 1 if using HTTP or 2 if using HTTPS [1]:`

and Started the Server Using below Command

java -jar ords.war standalone

Server is working fine locally , but as per Current Plan i want to make server Live over internet for that i want to Secure Using SSL HTTPS Configuration , I exactly didn't know the Steps that how to Achieve this. I just have select `Require HTTPS` from Work-space in Instance Setting , but its didn't worked as instance was not accessible so i used below Command to Revert settings back

```
BEGIN
    APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.SET_PARAMETER('REQUIRE_HTTPS', 'N');
    commit;
end;
/
```

Want some useful suggestion for SSL/HTTPS Configuration

Answer (score 3):

Edit the file ..... `config/ords/standalone/standalone.properties`

Add the setting `jetty.secure.port=443` ( or whatever port needed )

That spins up the HTTPS service with a self-signed cert.

Next procure a certificate and set it in the configuration. There are multiple choices

1. Let's Encrypt which is details in my blog post http://krisrice.io/2018-05-09-ORDS-and-lets_encrypt/
2. SSL authorities. This could include converting the ssl cert format to a .der which is what ORDS requires.

In this case, you must run a command similar to the following to convert it and remove the encryption:

`openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.der -nocrypt`

Then again edit the `conf/ords/standalone/standalone.properties` adding

`ssl.cert=<path to yourdomain.crt>
ssl.cert.key=<path to yourdomain.der>
ssl.host=yourdomain`

This is in the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e87809/installing-REST-data-services.htm#AELIG7026

Or on oracle-base here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-standalone-mode

Comment: I have added `jetty.secure.port=443` to standalone.properties and restarted the ords , but now i am getting error on `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in self-signed.pem -out self-signed.der -nocrypt`
Error is `139778680584080:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: where did the cert files come from ?

Comment: ok i have followed your given link from oracle base on SSL Configuration (HTTPS)
`# Create a self-signed certificate in a JKS keystore.` and `# Create a PKCS12 keystore from the JKS keystore.`  and `# Extract the key and certificate in PEM format.` are successful  but `# Convert them to DER format.` is not working 
as giveing error `unable to load key`

Comment: If this is for the but testing do not use a self-signed cert.

Comment: so what should i do now ? my server is almost down

Comment: down? I'm missing some context what you are meaning.

Comment: after adding jetty.secure.port=443 to properties i restarted the ords and it's not accessible from browser error `Unable to Connect `

Comment: is this linux/unix? 443 is a privileged port. is the old 8080 or whatever still working ?

Comment: I Actually done like this as per oracle base `#jetty.port=8080

jetty.secure.port=8443`

Comment: if i enable 8080 then ords unable to start

Comment: I suggest you take this to a more chat/conversation based medium like slack ords channel.  https://orclapex.slack.com/messages/C0BJK2QF4

Comment: I dont have slack account

Comment: can you  join on https://adeelcoworkspace.slack.com/messages/CECHG7A5U/

Comment: goto http://apex.world and register it's a better medium for Q&A back and forth that SO which isn't meant for that

Comment: You mean you are not going help any more ?

Comment: not what I said at all. apex.world's slack channel have over 1k people for just ords/apex so you'll get much broad audience than just me

Comment: OK i have joined the slack